# Unable to use if condition inside an if condition in nginx configuration file app.conf

Tags: nginx

I am checking some IF condition (inside server directive), if it is passed then check other IF condition and if it is also passed then return some test. My code is as follows

```
if ($a != "Tree") {
if ($a != "Plant") { return 403 "It is not tree or plant"; 
 }
 }
```

When I am using this code I am getting error for second IF as  "if" directive is not allowed here.

Comment: Nginx's config is not a programming language and quite limited. And `if` directive should not be used usually. Better tell what's the real problem you want to solve and probably there is a better way to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check multiple conditions you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790)

In your case it would be:

```
if ($a != "Tree") { 
  set $test  no-tree; 
} 

if ($a != "Plant") { 
  set $test  "${test}+no-plant"; 
} 

if ($test = no-tree+no-plant) { 
    return 403 "It is not tree or plant";
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend using it unless its really necessary.